# Problem with auto pair a Bluetooth device

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, bluetooth, connection, home-automation

https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/test/simple-agent

I tried the Above Python script but getting a dialogue box 'Pairing Requested'. How to remove that dialogue box?

Comment: Do you expect that we debug the python script for you? In that script there is no message `Pairing Requested` raised.

Comment: I tried for 4 weeks and I didn't get how to disable that message. And where the message was coming?

Comment: Sometimes it is better to go a step backwards and get another view. What do you want to do in general? Why using just this script? Maybe there is another solution? Please address me with @Ingo, otherwise it may be possible that I don't see your reply.

Comment: @Ingo sir, I was tried with Bluetoothctl and btmgmt commands but they also out dated functionalities, which are removed. Bluetooth connection without monitor to receive Wi-Fi details for home automation. Thank you for responding sir.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to connect to bluetooth devices and it has never worked until I found a link that showed me how.
link here: 
https://www.cnet.com/g00/how-to/how-to-setup-bluetooth-on-a-raspberry-pi-3/?i10c.ua=1&i10c.encReferrer=aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbS8%3d&i10c.dv=7

Comment: Please take the [tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [helpcenter](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help). Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it is preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. In fact we're [enforcing this policy](http://meta.raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/842/5538): please edit so that the answer stands on its own should the link break in the future. If it is not edited within 48 hours it will be converted to Community Wiki.

Comment: @BlackOps-9-Elite sir, I am trying that pair a device without a monitor, so I need to connect all devices automatically.

Comment: @ViGoRa, The only way is to access a raspberry pis bluetooth adapter is this way, so you need a monitor in order for this to work I am afraid.

Comment: @BlackOps-9-Elite sir, I got but the raspberry pi in real time application, Bluetooth should be connected automatically to take Wi-Fi ssid and password to connect in a network. The Bluetooth Pairing is necessary in home automation. Thank you for responding.